# Cache busting not working with android browser

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, caching, browser-cache

Cache busting ( random javascript.js?1234123 ) is not working in android with default browser or chrome. 
The old file version is still loading from cache.. 
I confirmed cache busting is working on PC / iPhone / iPad, but is not working with android.
ex:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js<?php echo '?'.rand(); ?>"></script>
```

Comment: There needs to be an `=` sign after the random name I think or else it won't look like a proper query part.  (Not 100% sure that's true but it'd be the first thing I tried :-)

Comment: I think a query string doesn't necessarily need to contain &-separated key=value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with me not refreshing mobile devtools properly